# Golang: изменение реализации метода в run-time

Tags: golang, рефлексия

У меня есть реализация типа:

```
type A struct{
  name string
}

func (a A) getName() string {
  return "My name is " + a.name 
}
```

Как изменить реализацию метода getName во время выполнения?

**Обновление**

Переопределение таким образом, чтобы до переопределения "a.getName()" вызывало описанную реализацию, а после переопределения - новую.

Comment: @DarkGenius, уточните ваш вопрос. Вы имеете в виду перегрузку, переопределение или что-то другое?

Comment: @Expert, обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фукнция это превоклассное значение в Go. Можно сделать это имя полем, и присваивать ему значение:

```
package main

type Typ struct {
    foo func ()
}

func main() {
    t := Typ{}
    t.foo = func () {
        println("first implementation")
    }
    t.foo()
    t.foo = func () {
        println("second implementation")
    }
    t.foo()
}
```

выдаст:

```
first implementation
second implementation
```

**UPD**: Если хочется именно метод, то можно в методе вызывать изменяемое поле.

```
package main

type A struct {
}

var globalFoo = func () string {
    return "first"
}

func (a A) getName() string {
    return globalFoo()
}

func main() {
    a := A{}
    println(a.getName())
    globalFoo = func () string {
        return "second"
    }
    println(a.getName())
}
```

Но тот факт что вам такого хочется -- уже настораживает.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, спасибо за поправку.

Comment: @Alex Krass, нужно решение для случая, когда foo не определен в типе (см. пример в вопросе).

Comment: @DarkGenius например, хранить в глобальной переменной, обновил

Comment: Вряд ли это в точности то, что хотел (спрашивал) ТС. Изменилась же не реализация, а ссылка. К тому же обе реализации присутствовали в коде изначально.

Comment: всё потому что того, что просил ТС, слава богу, сделать нельзя

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам менять саму реализациию?

```
type A struct {
  name string
}

func (a A) returnString(n string, b bool) string {
  if n != "" {
    return "My name is " + n
  } else if b {
    return "My name is " + "Петя"
  } else {
    return "My name is " + a.name
  }
}

a := A{"Вася"}

fmt.Println(a.returnString("", false))
fmt.Println(a.returnString("Дима", false))
fmt.Println(a.returnString("", true))

My name is Вася
My name is Дима
My name is Петя
```

Это простой пример, можно сделать что-то боее красивое.

Comment: Вы исходите из предположения, что исходный вид метода может быть произвольным. Однако по условию задачи он зафиксирован, менять его нельзя.